# Logstash windows logs

Tags: logstash

i am having trouble finding the logs for logstash, i had configured windows servers to forward logs via **nxlog** using **rsyslog** in my linux machine, now i don't know where the logs are stored. i have looked in `/var/log/` directory but nothing is there.

From my windows hosts although i am receiving the logs to **Kibana**, can please anyone help me? also my hosts are showing as **fqdn** and **netbios** name, i can not attach the image as i do not have enough reputation posts, can someone please assist me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you started logstash, what config file did you use (it is the file specified after the -f flag)?

In that .conf file, there is an **input {}** section that shows you the file path (**path => file/path/for/logs**) that logstash is using to look for logs.

Alternatively, you may be sending the data received over TCP directly to Elasticsearch. You can query this using curl (or a web browser). Should be something like:
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty